# Round any decimal number up to the next tenth number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

In Microsoft Excel 2007, which formula is used to convert the following decimal values in this particular manner?

- 1.3      should convert to 10
- 2.5      should convert to 10
- 4.8      should convert to 10
- 5.1      should convert to 10
- 7.2      should convert to 10
- 10.1     should convert to 20
- 11.4     should convert to 20
- 13.9     should convert to 20
- 17.2     should convert to 20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the [Ceiling](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/ceiling-HP005209007.aspx) function.

For example, =CEILING(A1, 10) will round the value in A1 up to the nearest multiple of 10.

Answer (score 1):

`CEILING` is fine but you can also round to powers of 10 using ROUNDUP, so for this case

`=ROUNDUP(A1,-1)`